# UITableView as inputView for UITextField didSelectRowAtIndexPath randomly not fired

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableViewController that I'm using to override the inputView of a UITextField subclass. Sometimes the tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath stops getting fired until a user scolls the table and tries to click again. I can't seem to get a fix on what would cause the cells to become unresponsive. Most of the time it works great, but randomly the cells stop responding to touches until the user scrolls the tableview a bit.

I don't have any TapGestureRecognizers in the view to my knowledge, and have played around with overriding HitTest in the UITableViewCell, but can't seem to figure out the issue.

Any ideas on how to better debug this?

Here is the tableView controller code:

```
protocol MultiSelectPickerDelegate
{
    func didSelectOption(optionIndex:Int, group:Int)
}

class MultiSelectPicker: UITableViewController {

    var multiSelectGroups = [MultiSelectGroup](){
        didSet{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    var delegate:MultiSelectPickerDelegate?

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return multiSelectGroups.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return multiSelectGroups[section].multiSelectOptions.count
    }


    //MARK: UITableView datasourse function
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelectOption(indexPath.row, group: indexPath.section)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        label.text = multiSelectGroups[section].name
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyAppBlue()
        return view

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier")
        if cell == nil{
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = multiSelectGroups[indexPath.section].multiSelectOptions[indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: you assign MultiSelectPicker.view to UITextField.inputView ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem. On my table view it was not clicking very last row of my table on the first tap. It highlights it, but didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't being called. All the other rows work fine. But if I turn the tableview bounce on then it seems to solve the problem

[image]

Also try removing Show Selection on Touch in Interface Builder as follows:
[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to have made a difference. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My coworker noticed that the bouncing in the UITableView was what appeared to be causing the row selection to stop working temporarily. I disabled bouncing, and the issue has yet to reappear.