# UITextView InputView UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to implement a TableView that overrides a UITextViews InputView to provide the user with a searchable TableView which then populates the UITextField with the selected value.

I've search about a fair bit and the closest solution I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342175/uitableview-as-inputview-for-uitextfield-didselectrowatindexpath-randomly-not-fi) but I'm not sure how to associate the UITableViewController to my UITextViews InputView?

I can see that these functions are being called in the MultiSelectPicker...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

But these aren't which I'm fairly sure explains why I'm not seeing anything populated in the table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

I have changed the didSet so I know reloadData is being called from the main thread and still nothing.

```
var items = [NSObject](){
    didSet{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        });
    }
}
```

Its probably something to do with the way I'm setting the inputView in my main viewcontroller but I'm fairly new to iOS and Swift so I'm probably missing something basic.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mspEmployee: MultiSelectPicker!

    let employeePickerView = MultiSelectPicker()
    employeePickerView.items = self.oEmployees
    self.mspEmployee = employeePickerView
    self.txtEmployee.inputView = self.mspEmployee.view
```

This really is driving me mad so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass the UITextField and set the inputView to the view of your UITableView. Here is some of the implentation of something similar I did recently.

```
class BaseTextField: UITextField{

    //Base textfield so that all custom textfields inherit the disabling of certain uitextfield things
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        //disabling menu, autocorrection and copy paste functionality
        autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
        inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
        inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
    }

    override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
            UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
        }
        return false
    }
}


class OptionSelectText: BaseTextField{
    let picker:OptionPicker //this is the UITableViewController I Use for selecting values
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        picker = OptionPicker()
        picker.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        picker.delegate = self
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: picker.view.frame.width, height: 44))

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(OptionSelectText.pickerViewDoneAction))
        let flex = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let clearButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target:self, action: #selector(OptionSelectText.pickerClearAction))
        toolbar.setItems([clearButton, flex, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        inputView = picker.view
        inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying! - I've implemented the OptionSelectText as a new class but I'm getting an error with 'picker.delegate = self' saying cannot assign value of type 'OptionSelectText to type 'MultiSelectPickerDelegate' - how does OptionPicker differ from the MultiSelectPicker code you posted in the original? I am very new to this so apologies if these are silly questions

Comment: Just change the OptionPicker to use your multiselectpicker class

Comment: Yeah I changed that - is it because of the protocol implementation in MultiSelect perhaps - do you have that in your OptionSelect?                 class OptionSelectText: BaseTextField{
    let picker:MultiSelectPicker //this is the UITableViewController I Use for selecting values
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        picker = MultiSelectPicker()
        picker.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        picker.delegate = self

Comment: No you need to make the class OptionSelectText: BaseTextField, MultiSelectPickerDelegate{
}

Comment: Implementing the delegate correctly got those tableView functions firing and populating the table many thanks really appreciate you taking the time to help me out @Nathan Hart